# How to share video on WhatsApp without using UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, whatsapp

I am currently trying to enable the functionality to share a video on WhatsApp but without using UIActivityViewController, as Tik Tok does for example. When you click on "share" on WhatsApp, it directly redirects you to WhatsApp and contacts pop up so that you can share the video.

I kinda succeeded in sharing it but with ActivityViewController, this way:

```
 let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Rap God", withExtension: "mp4")!.relativePath
 let fileUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
 controller = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: fileUrl as URL)
 controller.uti = "net.whatsapp.movie"
 controller.presentOpenInMenu(from: CGRect.zero, in: self.view, animated: true)
```

I would be glad to know someone can help me out.

Comment: The one that tiktok is showing is also similar to a `UIActivityViewController`. What else do you need?

Comment: @PGDev well, it is similar but not exactly the same, then how can I execute the same code, that is to say redirect to WhatsApp to share the video?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `UIApplication's` `canOpenURL(_:)` and `open(_:options:completionHandler:)`,

```
let urlString = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60282744/how-to-share-video-on-whatsapp-without-using-uiactivityviewcontroller"
let shareString = "whatsapp://send?text=\(urlString)"
if let url = URL(string: shareString), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)  {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:]) { (completed) in
        print(completed)
    }
}
```

Comment: your answer seems to work, however could you tell me how can I do the same with a local video please?