# How to "preselect" UIActivityViewController Icon?

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to redirect the user to an app that could be selected in UIActivityViewController.

For example, the "Message" app is often shown in UIActivityViewController. How could I,in advance, directly redirect the user to this app without showing the UIActivityViewController?

I would be glad to know if someone can help me out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to share video on WhatsApp without using UIActivityViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60282744/how-to-share-video-on-whatsapp-without-using-uiactivityviewcontroller)

Comment: You've asked 3 similar questions with just different social networks. Please don't ask duplicates. Ask your doubts in the same question.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to open the `Messages` App, it's simple.

```
@IBAction func openMessagesApp(sender: UIButton){
    // Swift 3
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "sms:")!)

    // Swift 4
    UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "sms:")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one!

```
@IBAction func openMessagesApp(sender: UIButton){
   let sms = "sms:\(number)&body=\(message or link)"
   let url = URL(string:sms)!
   let shared = UIApplication.shared

    if(shared.canOpenURL(url)){
       shared.openURL(url)
     } else{
       print("unable to send message")
     }
}
```